# Find the smallest element in a list

Tags: python, element

I would like to find the smallest value of list `a`. I know that there is a function like `min()` to find the value but I would like do it work with a `for`-loop.
I get the error `Index out of range` with the `if`-Statement, but I don't know why.

```
a = [18,15,22,25,11,29,31]
n = len(a)

tmp = a[0]
for i in a:
   if(a[i] < tmp):
      tmp = a[i]
      print(tmp)
```

Comment: Because `for a in i` iterates over the *contents* of the list, **not** the *indices*; `a[18]` causes an `IndexError`.

Comment: As a side note, you probably want to move that `print` outside the loop, not inside. Otherwise, you're going to print out every lowest number seen so far, except the first (so it'll print `15`, then `11`… or, if you give it `[1, 2, 3, 4]` it'll print nothing at all).

Comment: Also, don't put parentheses around if conditions. This is Python, not C.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this and voting to close? How is this not a programming question? Sure, it's a novice question, but there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @abarnert not my close vote, but "simple typo" gets confusingly grouped in with "not a programming question" close reasons now.

Comment: @abarnert as for why downvote, "I know there's a right way to do this, but how can I do it the wrong way?" deserves more explanation than just "because I wanna".

Comment: @abarnert it's also a bit disappointing to see *"I get the error Index out of range... but I don't know why"* without even a cursory attempt to *find out what index is being used*, which would have solved this "problem" in seconds with a `print`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Good point. kojiro: I assumed his tutorial/textbook/teacher asked him to do it because it would help him learn, or he thought on his own that it would help him learn, either of which seems reasonable. It's worth knowing how to use the stdlib, but it's also worth knowing how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you iterate over a list in Python (`for e in l:`), you do not iterate over the indices but over the elements directly. So you should write:

```
for e in a:
    if(e < tmp):
        tmp = e
        print(tmp)
```

Answer (score 2):

As already said, you mixed iteration over elements and looping over indexes. The solution for iteration over elements was already presented, so for completeness I would like to write the other solution:

```
a = [18,15,22,25,11,29,31]
n = len(a)

tmp = a[0]
for i in range(n):
    if(a[i] < tmp):
        tmp = a[i]
        print(tmp)
```

Edit: changed `xrange` to `range` as per comment bellow.

Comment: Considering that the OP appears to be using the Python 3 `print` function rather than Python 2 `print` statement, you shouldn't be using `xrange` in an answer.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, you are right. I use Python 2, but always do `from __future__ import print_function`, so I missed that.

Comment: I would use enumerate anyway

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: No reason for `enumerate` here; the only use for the `i` is in `a[i]`, so you just as well just for `for e in a`. I'm pretty sure jure was just showing how the OP _could_ do it with indices if you really wanted to, not suggesting that he should.

Comment: @abarnert, I was not necessarily on about this case, I meant if I were going to index a list I would use enumerate not range, the OP would be better off learning to use enumerate

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yes, definitely. And it's one of the next things the OP should probably learn about, so worth mentioning.